# Subviews frame not updating after view.center command

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, coordinates, cgrect

What I have are these different views as shown in picture: the main view is the `container`, inside that there is the `boxSentence`, inside the `boxSentence` there is the `subView`, and inside `subView` the different text labels with the gray box `boxWord`. Then there is this other view `boxAnswer` that is a draggable element that i created that can only be dropped inside the `boxWord` (I pass the `boxWord` to my custom class of the `boxAnswer` to check his position (frame)).

[image: Main scenario]

In this scenario everything works fine, the `boxAnswer` can only be placed 
inside the boxWord

[image: Working scenario]

Then for adjusting the graphics of the whole view I want to put my `subView` with all his actual subviews in the center of `boxSentence`. To do that I used `subView.center = boxSentence.center` and I obtained what I wanted.

[image: subView in the center]

Now, the problem comes when I try to drag and drop `boxAnswer` inside the new position of `boxWord`, it doesn't work, but if I try to drag and drop it where `boxWord` was before moving it to the center it does work.

[image: Problem here]

It seems like that when you do `subView.center = boxSentence.center` it only affects the frame of `subView`, but it doesn't affect the frames of its subviews. Any suggestions on how to resolve the problem?

CODE:

```
// creo box dove inserire la frase
let boxSentence = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: container.frame.width, height: container.frame.height/2))
container.addSubview(boxSentence)
boxSentence.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#49eb34")

let subView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: container.frame.width, height: 70))


let label1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
label1.text = esercizio.ctsex![0].first_sentence
label1.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
label1.sizeToFit()

let boxWord = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: label1.frame.maxX, y: 0, width: 100, height: 60))
boxWord.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

let label2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: boxWord.frame.maxX, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
label2.text = esercizio.ctsex![0].second_sentence
label2.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
label2.sizeToFit()

subView.addSubview(label1)
subView.addSubview(boxWord)
subView.addSubview(label2)
subView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
boxSentence.addSubview(sottoView)
subView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: label2.frame.maxX-label1.frame.minX, height: 80)
subView.center = boxSentence.center


let coordrisposta = CGRect(x: boxFrase.frame.minX, y: boxFrase.frame.maxY, width: 80.0, height: 40.0)
let boxAnswer = DragObject(frame: coordrisposta, vistap: boxWord)
boxAnswer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

container.addSubview(rispostaBox)
```

CLASS DragObject OF boxAnser:

```
import UIKit

// CLASSE CHE CREA UNA VISTA CHE PUO ESSERE SPOSTATA SOLO ALL'INTERNO DI UNA VISTA PASSATA DA PARAMETRO

class DragObject: UIView {

    var vista: UIView
    var initcoord: CGRect

    init(frame: CGRect, vistap: UIView){
        self.vista = vistap
        self.initcoord = frame
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("touch began")
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
       var touch : UITouch! = touches.first as UITouch?
       self.center = touch.location(in: self.superview)        
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        var coorv = vista.frame
        print(coorv)

        let coord1 = (touches.first?.location(in: self.superview))!
        let destinazione1 = CGPoint(x: coorv.minX, y: coorv.minY)
        let destinazione2 = CGPoint(x: coorv.maxX, y: coorv.maxY)

        if coord1.x > destinazione1.x && coord1.y > destinazione1.y && coord1.x < destinazione2.x && coord1.y < destinazione2.y {
            print("OK")
            self.frame = vista.frame
        } else {
            print("fuori")
            self.frame = initcoord
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frames of UIView is it's coordinate relative to it's parent bounds(internal coordinate system of UIView that is coordinate system for subview of that view).
For example we have UIViewController with 2 views:

```
let redView = UIView()
redView.backgroundColor = .red
redView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 100, height: 100)
self.view.addSubview(redView)

let greenView = UIView()
greenView.backgroundColor = .green
greenView.frame = CGRect(x: 25, y:25, width:50, height: 50)
redView.addSubview(greenView)

print(redView.frame)
/*
(20.0, 20.0, 100.0, 100.0)
redView is placed self.view.bounds.origin.x + 20 and self.view.bounds.origin.y + 20
*/
print(greenView.frame)
/*
(25.0, 25.0, 50.0, 50.0)
green is placed redView.bounds.origin.x + 25 and redView.bounds.origin.y + 25
*/
print(redView.convert(greenView.frame, to: self.view))
/*
(45.0, 45.0, 50.0, 50.0)
converted frame of greenView from redViews bounds to of self.view bounds.
*/
```

So the problem inside DragObject, you pass frame and view coordinates that reflect their place relative to subView view origin.
Meanwhile DragObject is subview of container view and when you receive touch coordinates you get coordinates relative to container view.
You could fix it by converting vista.frame to DragObject superview coordinate system.
Here is fullCode of override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set, with event: UIEvent?) in DragObject

```
var coorv = vista.superview!.convert(vista.frame, to: self.superview!)
print(coorv)

let coord1 = (touches.first?.location(in: self.superview))!
let destinazione1 = CGPoint(x: coorv.minX, y: coorv.minY)
let destinazione2 = CGPoint(x: coorv.maxX, y: coorv.maxY)

if coord1.x > destinazione1.x && coord1.y > destinazione1.y && coord1.x < destinazione2.x && coord1.y < destinazione2.y {
    print("OK")
    self.frame = coorv
} else {
    print("fuori")
    self.frame = initcoord
}
```

Comment: Ooh ok now I see, different coordinates related to different superViews. Very clear and exhaustive thanks man!